# Copy data from list to Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

We have a list with first name, email address, and status. We have a Data extension with the same attribute. We want to transfer the data from the list to the data extension on daily basis.

How we can send the data to DE from a list.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create an Automation with an SQL Query activity. SQL would pick records from `_ListSubscribers` Data View by `ListID` (you can find ID directly on the page with all lists) and then if you have additional attributes, e.g. "First_Name", you would need to pull them from `_EnterpriseAttribute` -

```
SELECT
    ea.First_Name, /* your additional attribute */
    AddedBy,
    AddMethod,
    CreatedDate,
    DateUnsubscribed,
    EmailAddress,
    ListID,
    ListName,
    ListType,
    Status,
    SubscriberID,
    SubscriberKey,
    SubscriberType
FROM _ListSubscribers ls
LEFT JOIN ent._EnterpriseAttribute ea ON ea._SubscriberID = ls.SubscriberID
WHERE ListID = xxx /* your list's ID */
```

Then only select Overwrite or other data action, depending on your needs, and set the daily schedule in the Automation.

You can also follow [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_export_list_enhanced.htm&type=5) to do that manually.

Comment: This'll work, but `ListID` is a int/number.  Reducing data conversions will definitely improve the performance of queries -- especially against the dataviews.

Comment: There is also a SSJS solution possible (and also WSProxy) but it is likely less performant than this SQL. I wanted to mention it as an option though as there are some use cases for it and wanted to keep awareness of all the available options.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, yep, removed the quotes around `ListID`.